# looping and only displaying attributes which are present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to only show the attributes that are present on my index page. Here is my code so far, and it does work:

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
<strong>Name: <%= contact.name %></strong>

<% if contact.phone %>
  <p>Phone number: <%= contact.phone !="nil" %></p>
<% end %>
<% if contact.category !="nil" %>
  <p>Category: <%= contact.category %></p>
<% end %>
<% if contact.area !="nil" %>
  <p>Area: <%= contact.area %></p>
<% end %>
<% if contact.website !="nil" %>
  <p>Website: <%= contact.website %></p>
<% end %>
<% if contact.email%>
  <p>Email: <%= contact.email !="nil" %></p>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

My questions is

Is there a neater way for me do this (i.e. rather than specifying the if for each attribute)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <strong>Name: <%= contact.name %></strong>
  <%["phone", "category", "area", "website", "email"].each do |attr| %>
    <% unless contact.send(attr).blank?%>
      <p>
       <%= attr.capitalize%>
      </p>
      <%= contact.send(attr.to_sym)%>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: that looks good, thanks. It does seem to need me to say that the attribute !="nil" but that doesn't work when you do attr.to_sym. Is an empty string not recognised as being a non-existent attribute?

Comment: I modified it a bit.`send` works with strings to. So `to_sym` is not needed `contact.send(attr)` is the same as `contact.phone`.